# how would one sum a range of numbers within a certain value?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, range

I have an array of values like so

```
 nums = [2.5, 1, 9, 9.9, 1.6, 5.4, 3.2, 4.4, 4, 5.2, 5, 6]
```

Is there a pythonic way to sum all values within this array that are between a certain value? For example, if my range was 2.5-6, I would expect to get 2.5 + 5.4 + 3.2 + 4.4 + 4 + 5.2 + 5 + 6 = 35.7. I'm also open to using numpy to solve this as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since no one has offered a numpy solution yet, here you go:

```
>>> nums = np.array([2.5, 1, 9, 9.9, 1.6, 5.4, 3.2, 4.4, 4, 5.2, 5, 6])
>>> nums[(2.5 <= nums) & (nums <= 6)].sum()
35.700000000000003
```

Although, I tried some simple tests, and I'm not sure that there's much speed benefit.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> nums = [2.5, 1, 9, 9.9, 1.6, 5.4, 3.2, 4.4, 4, 5.2, 5, 6]
>>> sum([n for n in nums if 2.5 <= n <= 6])
35.7
>>> 2.5 + 5.4 + 3.2 + 4.4 + 4 + 5.2 + 5 + 6
35.7
```

Comment: Prefer `sum(n for n in nums ...)` over `sum([n for n in nums ...])`. The former creates a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), which conserves memory.

Comment: Prefer `if 2.5 <= n <= 6` to `if n <=6 and n >=2.5`, for readability

Answer (score 2):

It can also be done by sorting and then bisecting to find the slice of the list to sum:

```
>>> nums = [2.5, 1, 9, 9.9, 1.6, 5.4, 3.2, 4.4, 4, 5.2, 5, 6]
>>> nums.sort()
>>> import bisect
>>> min = 2.5
>>> max = 6
>>> sum(nums[bisect.bisect_right(nums, min)-1:bisect.bisect_left(nums, max)+1])
35.7
```

Comment: This actually looks the most perfomance-optimized from all anwers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, lets assume you have your variables `min` and `max` set. Then you can type:

```
min = 2.5
max = 6
sum = sum( i if i>=min and i<=max else 0 for i in nums )
```

Greets!

Answer (score 1):

Use `masked_outside()`:

```
import numpy as np
nums = [2.5, 1, 9, 9.9, 1.6, 5.4, 3.2, 4.4, 4, 5.2, 5, 6]
np.ma.masked_outside(nums, 2.5, 6).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(filter(lambda x: x>=2.5 and x<=6,nums))
```

Comment: is there a benefit to filter and lambda, over using a comprehension?

Comment: @JamesK: No, there is not